# how to serialize using entityframework ICollection 'my way'

Tags: json, entity-framework, serialization

i have

table of users. - key `IdUser` , and other colsumns...

table of perms key `IdPerm`, and column  `PermName`

and table of UserPerms key `IdUserPerm`and columns `IdPerm` `IdUser` and `Value`

so when i select this user using `Entity Framework` and return it as json from api i get

```
 { IdUser : 1, login: "xx", name: "xxx",
  UserPerms : [
   {IdUserPerm : 1, IdUser : 1, idPerm: 1, value: 1, idPermNavigation: {idperm: 1, PermName:"Feature1"}}
   {IdUserPerm : 2, IdUser : 1, idPerm: 2, value: 2, idPermNavigation: {idperm: 2, PermName:"Feature2"}}
   {IdUserPerm : 3, IdUser : 1, idPerm: 3, value: 5, idPermNavigation: {idperm: 3, PermName:"Feature3"}}
  ]
 }
```

is there any way i can configure this json serializer or .net core EF so i get result

```
  UserPerms :{permname:value, next..}
```

so in this example to get

```
{IdUser:1, login:"xx", name:"yy",..., UserPerms:{Feature1:1, Feature2:2, Feature3:5}}
```

or any way to redesign DB so EF got this as 'default' ?

thanks and regards !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can workaround by create DTO like

```cs
class UserPermResult {
    int IdUser;
    string Login;
    ...
    ICollection<Perm> UserPerms;
}

class Perm {
    string Name;
    int Value;
}
```

and use Select linQ

```cs
values.Select(f=> new UserPermResult {
    IdUser = f.IdUser,
    ...
    UserPerms = f.UserPerms.Select(p=> new Perm{
       Name = p.IdPermNavigation?.PermName,
       Value = p.Value
    })
});
```

Comment: thanks i will try :) 

ps. is there any way to get my result by 'default' ? redesign DB in some way so EF get it like this by default ?

Comment: You can move the PermName column to UserPerms table and remove IdUserPerm key, (IdUser, IdPerm) will be key. Then you can  drop Perms table but I think redesign the database is not a good solution.